# Unity google play services login dont work properly

Tags: unity, leaderboards, google-play-services

I have searched everywhere on the internet and I have found nothing about the problem I am encountering.

I am trying to implement google play services to my game (leaderboards especially) and I have made that "work" somehow. Here is the code:

```
void Start()
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate ();

    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
    {
        if (success)
        {
            Debug.Log("Logging in: Success");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Logging in: Failed");
        }
    });
}
```

The game opens properly and it shows that green window which then disappears and a "loading" icon appears turning in a circle. But after that it disappears too and the window which lists and ask you which account to link with the game does not appear, as it is supposed to do(which "ends" the logging in).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered this problem before. This happens if you are using an unsigned app. You should have a keystore for your game in order for GPG to work. I'm not sure if you need at least one version uploaded on Google Developers Console, so maybe someone with that knowledge can share if you need that or not?